# Error ModuleNotFoundError when importing cython module

Tags: python, cython

I am getting an error importing a cython module that baffles me. The structure of my files are shown below. When I run the jupyter module main.ipynb, I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Act'
```

My directories and files:

```
├── main.ipynb  (see below)
├── __init__.py  (empty file)
└── util
    ├── Act.pyx       (see below)
    ├── __init__.py    (empty file)
    ├── setup.py       (see below)
    ├── Simu.py     (see below)
```

*main.ipynb*

```
from util.Simu import Simu 
...
```

*Simu.py*

```
from Act import Act
class Simu:
...
```

*Act.pyx*

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
cdef class Act:
...
```

*setup.py*

```
import setuptools
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy
import pandas

setup(ext_modules=(cythonize(Extension("Act", ["Act.pyx"]))),
      include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
      requires=['numpy', 'Cython'])
```

Based on some forums I added empty `__init__` files but nothing seems to be working. I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: can you `from Act cimport Act` ?

Comment: @JacobIRR  I am very new to Cython, so I am probably doing something wrong. In \util directory made a file test. py and in it I put < from Act cimport Act> it gives " SyntaxError: invalid syntax" error.

Comment: And how do you build your cython code? Do you build at all?

Comment: @ead. I did  >python setup.py build_ext --inplace and it built it.

Comment: @JacobIRR I think cimport is *only* for use within Cython files (to read the definitions in another Cython fiels), so is *not* what is wanted here. I'd suggest trying `from .Act import Act` (i.e. a relative import) from within Simu.py